# how to convert an 720p file to 360p using ffmpeg with the help of gpu

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, nvidia, scaling

i want to convert a 720 p video into 360 p video with the help of GPU. i am using this command: `"ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -resize 480x360 -i input -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 249K output"`
,but the output file is larger than input file.
i need to reduce the size of input file.

Comment: Have you tried searching? The article below is searched. Is this the same question? [resize-smaller-ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/624563/how-to-resize-a-video-to-make-it-smaller-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: @myeongkilkim yeah, but they don't use gpu for processing. I want to use gpu

Answer (score 4):

I managed to compress 720 P video with size 110MB to be 15 MB with below command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=-1:360 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -c:a copy output.mp4
```